# Using Office Fabric UI icons in a SPFx extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, office-ui-fabric-react

I want to add an icon to one of my buttons on my SPFx list extension. In the JSON, I can amend this for an url for an icon to my CDN, but how about if I just want to use office fabric UI, any ideas?

```
"items": {
    "COMMAND_1": {
      "title": { "default": "Print"  },
      "iconImageUrl": "icons/request.png",
      "type": "command"
    } 
},
```

Above is where you would enter the url if you were going to use a CDN for the icon.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 9):

This is currrently a SPFx limitation. You cannot directly use Fabric UI Icons as command set icons in SPFx list extension.

Currently SPFx extension allows you only 2 ways to set extension icon,

1) setting external image icon (which you are already using)

2) Use base-64 encoded image

You create your own image or download the fabric UI image(s) and [convert them to Base64](https://www.base64-image.de/) and use that in the `iconImageUrl` property.

Reference - [Configure SPFx extension icon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/basics/configure-extension-icon)

UserVoice - [Allow to use Office UI Fabric Icons and other fonts as Command Set icons](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/31781332-allow-to-use-office-ui-fabric-icons-and-other-font)

You can upvote the above UserVoice entry.